# Why are there double quotes in my Podfile.lock file?

Tags: cocoapods, podfile

The following contents is my footer content in Podfile.lock:

```
SPEC CHECKSUMS:

  RxSwift: af5680055c4ad04480189c52d28385b1029493a6
  SDWebImage: '098e97e6176540799c27e804c96653ee0833d13c'
  ...


PODFILE CHECKSUM: 1985f3107c446b3ecb03cb8e483a9dea9f528a77

COCOAPODS: 1.2.0.beta.1
```

Why is the SDWebImage's checksum within double quotations?

Maybe Some bugs for cocoapods-1.2.0.beta.1?

But my colleagues don't have this problem. And I'm sure we are using the same version for cocoapods. It will leading llvm reporting error when compiling.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have committed a issue in Github page: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6255

It seems like using different versions of psyche.